# Cant call my method on object from arraylist

Tags: c#, collections, unity-game-engine

I'm calling `getName()` method from Achiv class on an ArrayList in `printAchiv()` method located in Achievements script and it throws an error.

Here is the error message that I get on the line `Debug.Log("Achiv "+i+": "+ achivList[i].getName());`:

> Type `object' does not contain a definition for` getName' and no
> extension method `getName' of type` object' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm just trying to access value of var "name" from obejct in collection.

Achiv class :

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Achiv: MonoBehaviour 
{

    public string name;

    public Achiv(string name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

Achievements script :

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Achievements: MonoBehaviour 
{

    public ArrayList achivList = new ArrayList();

    void Start() 
    {
        achivList.Add(
            new Achiv("First name", "Descirptionn", false));
            
        achivList.Add(
            new Achiv("Second name", "Descirptionnn", false));

        printAchiv();
    }

    void printAchiv() 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= achivList.Count - 1; i++)
            Debug.Log("Achiv " + i + ": " + achivList[i].getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `List<Achiv>` instead of `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` is archaic, not type safe shouldn't be used anymore.

Indexer of `ArrayList` returns `object` that's why you get the error. Try the following.

```
public List<Achiv> achivList = new List<Achiv>();
```

Apart from this,

- Don't expose `List` publicly, prefer `ReadOnlyCollection` or `IEnumerable`.
- Prefer `foreach` over `for` unless there is a good reason.
- `printAchiv` doesn't follow proper naming convention, In c# we use "CamelCase", Rename it to `PrintAchiv`.
- get/set methods are for java style languages which doesn't supports properties. In c# we use properties instead. Create a property namely `Name`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the elements inside the `ArrayList` are stored as `object`. Thus `achivList[i]` returns an `object`, which does not provide the `getName()` method.
Either you can add a cast:

```
            Debug.Log("Achiv "+i+": "+ (Achiv)achivList[i].getName());
```

or you can switch to a generic List:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Achievements: MonoBehaviour {


    public  List<Achiv> achivList = new List<Achiv>();


    void Start () {

        achivList.Add (new Achiv("First name", "Descirptionn", false));
        achivList.Add (new Achiv("Second name", "Descirptionnn", false));


        printAchiv();

    }


    void printAchiv(){

        for (int i = 0; i <= achivList.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            Debug.Log("Achiv "+i+": "+ achivList[i].getName());
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList operates with Objects. You need to cast result of array indexing to Achiv:

```
(achivList[i] as Achiv).getName()
```

Comment: It should be `(Achiv)achivList[i]`. The puprose of using `as` operator is quite different.

Comment: Then probably ((Achiv)achivList[i]).getName() which reminded me of my other car :)

Comment: @Tarec what would be that different purpose? The only difference I see is a different exception if the cast fails...